# PHP Ajax to Display Clicked Result

Tags: php, ajax

I have the codes to search autocomplete from MySQL and the match query can be clicked and direct me to a new page. How can i have the result of the clicked queries to be displayed in the new page w/out using any URL from database because I need to avoid using lots of HTML files. Thank you.

```html
<p id="searchresults">
<?php
 // PHP5 Implementation - uses MySQLi.
 // mysqli('localhost', 'yourUserbookTitle', 'yourPassword', 'yourDatabase');
 $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'book');
 
 if(!$db) {
  // Show error if we cannot connect.
  echo 'ERROR: Could not connect to the database.';
 } else {
  // Is there a posted query string?
  if(isset($_POST['queryString'])) {
   $queryString = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryString']);
   
   // Is the string length greater than 0?
   if(strlen($queryString) >0) {
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM bookinfo WHERE bookTitle LIKE '%" . $queryString . "%'");
    
    if($query) {
     // While there are results loop through them - fetching an Object.
     
     // Store the category id
     $bookTitle = 0;
     while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
      if($result->bookTitle != $bookTitle) { // check if the category changed
       echo '<span class="category">'.$result->bookTitle.'</span>';
       $bookTitle = $result->bookTitle;
      }
             echo '<a href="'.$result->url.'">';
             echo '<img src="search_images/'.$result->bookimage.'" alt="" />';
             
             $bookTitle = $result->bookTitle;
             if(strlen($bookTitle) > 35) { 
              $bookTitle = substr($bookTitle, 0, 35) . "...";
             }             
             echo '<span class="searchheading">'.$bookTitle.'</span>';
             
             $author = $result->author;
             if(strlen($author) > 80) { 
              $author = substr($author, 0, 80) . "...";
             }
             
             echo '<span>'.$author.'</span></a>';
            }
            echo '<span class="seperator"><a href="http://www.marcofolio.net/sitemap.html" title="Sitemap">Nothing interesting here? Try the sitemap.</a></span><br class="break" />';
    } else {
     echo 'ERROR: There was a problem with the query.';
    }
   } else {
    // Dont do anything.
   } // There is a queryString.
  } else {
   echo 'There should be no direct access to this script!';
  }
 }
?>
</p>
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: please help. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I get your problem right, but *if* you need to display a new page with the selected book data/review/comments, I would add :

```
echo '<span>'.$author.'</span></a>'; /* after this line */
echo '<span>Read more > <a href="newpage.php?id='.$bookID.'">click here</a></span>'; /* where $bookID id the ID column in your DB */
```

Then, on the new page, retrieve data from DB according to $bookID value and display it...